# How can new users create their own usernames in SharePoint 2010

Tags: user-accounts

I have read that in SharePoint 2003 there was a web part whereby users can create their own usernames using a web part. I am on FBA (Claim-based).

Can this functionality be achieved in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something that's possible OOTB. Even with FBA, you'll need additional code ([codeplex has a great one](http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/)) to create the accounts in the FBA store. You could build a request page for which would allow anonymous users access to request a login, specifying their user name.

Comment: As usual, to the point solution from @David